# jquery get button value and select option with this value (Smarty)

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I have this code in my tpl file:

```
<select id="id_order_state" class="form-control" name="id_order_state">
      {foreach from=$states item=state}
        <option value="{$state['id_order_state']|intval}"{if isset($currentState) && $state['id_order_state'] == $currentState->id} selected="selected" disabled="disabled"{/if}>{$state['name']|escape}</option>
      {/foreach}
</select>
```

Also i have this code:

```
{foreach from=$states item=state}
      <p value="{$state['id_order_state']|intval}" class="btn btn-default">{$state['name']|escape}</p>
{/foreach}
```

what i am trying to do is when i click on a specific p item, automatically the option under the select box to get the value of the clicked p item and be the selected option of select box. Generally i am trying to change the select options to clickable buttons and i want to make it tricky via jquery..How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add this script just before the close of your `body`:

```
<script>
    $('p.btn').click(function () {
        $('#id_order_state').val($(this).attr('value'));
    });
</script>
```

Depending on whether you use the *btn* css class also for other paragraphs, the selector might need to be more precise.

But it detects the click on a paragraph, gets the *value* attribute and assigns it to the select control.

I am not sure why you have used the *disabled* attribute on the selected option. You might want to also change that attribute when the value of the select list is changed.